# Save a list as a value in the sparse matrix

Tags: performance-tuning, sparse-arrays

I am interested in save a list (the size of the list is two) of numbers in the sparse matrix, but this is not supported.
Maybe you familiar with some workarounds or any suggestion on another data structure?

```
example = 
 SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> {2, 3}, {2, 2} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 3, {1, 3} -> 
    4}]
```

Comment: is `"{2, 3}"` (instead of `{2, 3}`) acceptable?

Comment: .. or `FromDigits[{2, 3}, x]`?

Comment: I want to do computation after the definition. So saving the data as String may slowing the calculation.

Comment: how about using a 3D array instead of 2D: `rules = {{1, 1} -> {2, 3}, {2, 2} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 3, {1, 3} -> 4};SparseArray[ Flatten[rules /.    Rule[a_, b_] :>     Thread[(Append[a, #] & /@ Range[Length@If[Head[b] === List, b, {b}]]) -> b]]]`?

Comment: I suspect that you want to use `SparseArray` for something for which it was not made for. If you tell us what you _actually_ want to do, then, maybe, we can tell you how to do it with `SparseArray` or another suitable data type.

Comment: @Henrik, I try to speed up my code that calculates Loopy Belief Propagation. I implemented LBP with using Association, but this implementation not efficient in dense and huge graphs. Then I try to reimplement LBP using matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hacky workaround.

```
X = {{1, 1} -> 2, {1, 1} -> 3, {2, 2} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 3, {1, 3} -> 4}
A = With[{spopt = SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions"]},
   Internal`WithLocalSettings[
    SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> List}],
    SparseArray[X, {3, 3}, 0],
    SetSystemOptions[spopt]
    ]
   ];
Normal[A]
```

> {{{2, 3}, 0, 4}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}

Usually, one uses this with `"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Total` for additive assembly. The default value of `"TreatRepeatedEntries"` is `First`.

Overall, Mathematica is quite inconsistent with the handling of sparse array entries with head `List`. Any other (symbolic) head work seems to work without any problems. So if you do not rely on packed arrays as entries, you can also use this:

```
example = SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> list[2, 3], {2, 2} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 
    3, {1, 3} -> 4}]
```

Comment: Thank you @Henrik. I a little bit confused by the following fact when I update the sparse matrix (which I created according to your advice) I get `List`. `A[[1, 3]] = {1, 55};Head@A`

Comment: @KirilDanilchenko That's one of things I meant with "inconsistent". Notice that most routines for (and actually also the data structure of) `SparseArray` are optimized for matrices with entries only in one of the following data types: `Real`, `Integer`, or `Complex`. Everything beyond that can be considered as luxury, in particular since most other programming languages do not support anything beyond. Have also a look at `Association`: It provides more flexibility in many ways, but it is also less performant for several tasks.